# Where can I get a mystery box?

Tags: pokemon-go

Where can I find a mystery box in Pokémon Go? I saw the news about the upcoming event involving shiny Meltan and want one, but I don’t have a mystery box.

Answer (score 14):

You can't just find that box in PoGo, you need to trade with a Pokémon Let's Go account to get it. If you don't have it and don't know anyone who does either, you'll be able to get a single Meltan from the Special Study I imagine - I haven't completed it myself, but like other Special Studies (Mew, etc.) it should provide you with one Pokémon to catch and a bunch of Candy. Since Meltan requires 400 Candy to evolve though, it's going to be a pain to evolve it without the Mystery Box.

Comment: When you transfer Pokemon to Let's Go you get the mystery box which can only be open once a week and works like a lucky egg that spawns Meltan around you current location for 30 minutes only for you.  The special research provides one Meltan and 5 extra candies.

Comment: 5? Damn that's stingy, I think it was 20 for the two other studies.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of [Pokémon Go and Pokémon Home integration](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=all&s=accessories-and-services&f=sending-pokemon-to-pokemon-home), you can receive a Mystery Box by transferring Pokémon into your Pokémon Home storage. This requires you to connect your Pokémon Go account with a Nintendo Account.

**Linking Accounts**

1. Click on the Pokéball icon and go to settings on the top-right of the screen
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "Pokémon Home"
3. Follow the on-screen sign-on options to sign into your Nintendo account

**Transferring Pokémon**

1. Click on the Pokéball icon and go to settings on the top-right of the screen
2. Scroll to the bottom and click "Pokémon Home"
3. Click "Send Pokemon", and then follow the on-screen steps to transfer your Pokémon into Pokémon Home.

After you transfer Pokémon over to Pokémon Home, you will receive a Mystery Box.